# Can I install Windows 7 on Intel Core Duo 32 bit processor?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, cpu

I have a Lenovo 3000 N100 076885Q laptop which has inbuilt Windows XP 32 bit. The processor is Intel Core Duo and currently the RAM is 2.5 GB (initially it was 0.5 GB; I added 2 GB later). The available disk space on my `C:` drive (where I wish to install Windows 7) is 30 GB. However, whenever I try to install Windows 7, it's not getting completed successfully.

[update 1: During installation, it restarts and after the windows logo comes in I'm getting a blue screen error: 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Op2r.jpg)
]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Yes;  Of course you can install Windows on a PC with a Intel Core Duo processor.

Comment: Then why could not I? Whenever I try to install Windows 7, I get a blue screen error and can't proceed further. I tried to install it even in safe mode. But was not successful.

Comment: How are you getting into safe mode if your booting to a Windows 7 installation media?  You need to format the HDD, then install Windows 7, your system meets the requirements for windows 7

Comment: It does sound like you are trying to install it on the same partition as your windows XP install. Please make sure you know what you're getting in to. If you are planning to replace XP with windows 7, know that you WILL erase all your data. And that you must intentionally erase your data by reformatting the partition before installation

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could try is checking the SATA Controler is set to `AHCI` or changing the `ACPI` setting in `BIOS`. If it is ON change it to OFF and vice versa.

Comment: however it is highly recommended, even a "must" to format your HDD before installing the windows 7 over the XP as @Ramhound mentioned , you can backup you data to an external storage using a live linux distro in a bootable usb drive

Comment: The ACPI is turned on. However, there is no option to change this setting in BIOS. Are recommending to format my C: drive? Will this guarantee the  windows 7 installation? Otherwise I need to install XP again.

Comment: unfortunately nothing is guaranteed , since the bsod you had can be triggered by different issues , although formating the hdd is mandatory if you are going to do this manually , or you can give a try to those software like Laplink’s PCmover software ..... which obviously require a working operation system to move from , so its up to you to make the choice , and what i advice is to always backup your data

Answer (score -1):

> I wonder whether it's possible at all to install Windows 7 on my
>   laptop?

Yes, it capable to run Windows 7. Make sure you don't using broken installation media (scratched CD for example.) Try first to simply copy installation CD to some place just to verify all files are readable. Make sure CD/DVD drive can read that disk on your laptop. Run [memtest](http://www.memtest.org/) tool from live CD and be sure your laptop didn't get any errors after at least 2-3 passes. Run diagnostic software from live CDs, particularly [gsmartcontrol](http://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.net/home/) that read internal status of HDD from [SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.), if attributes 5, 196,1997 has value greater than zero, than HDD should be replaced. Run also long SMART test to be make sure all sectors of HDD are good

Comment: I'm using a bootable USB drive.

Comment: Try then first to check RAM with memtest86. Check also if ACPI in BIOS is enabled. Screenshot you attached usually come up on hardware errors or incorrect drivers and since it stuck on installation it is high probability that there hardware involved. Can you burn windows 7 to DVD and try to install it from optical drive. Sometimes installation of windows from USB devices can stuck